# Math - Get x & y coordinates at intervals along a line

Tags: actionscript-3, math, coordinates, algebra

I'm trying to get x and y coordinates for points along a line (segment) at even intervals. In my test case, it's every 16 pixels, but the idea is to do it programmatically in ActionScript-3.

I know how to get slope between two points, the y intercept of a line, and a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>, I just can't recall / figure out how to use slope or angle to get a and b (x and y) given c.

[image: visualization]

Does anyone know a mathematical formula to figure out a and b given c, y-intercept and slope (or angle)? (AS3 is also fine.)

Comment: Your graph describes exactly how to do it...

Comment: Found an article on what I'm looking for... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Point class built in to Flash has a wonderful set of methods for doing exactly what you want. Define the line using two points and you can use the "interpolate" method to get points further down the line automatically, without any of the trigonometry.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#interpolate()

Comment: Although this solves my problem, I'm curious what the `flash.geom.Point.interpolate` method does.

Comment: Probably a bunch of optimized trig math, just at a lower level.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose I could just use interpolate once per line, then use the dX between the start point and the first interpolated point, and plug multiples into `y = mx + b` to get the rest and save on more complicated calculations.

Comment: Take a look at all the various point methods. There's a lot of really helpful things in there beyond interpolate. polar() in particular can be great if you know the angle you're working with.

Comment: I figured out interpolating between two points is really simple, no trig required. `p1:Point`, the origin, and `p2:Point` the end point. `a:Point` is a point between p1 and p2. `loc:Number` is a ratio from p1 to p2, how far down the line to go. `loc = .25` would be a quarter of the way from p1 towards p2. `a.x = p1.x * (1 - loc) + p2.x * loc;` and `a.y = p1.y * (1 - loc) + p2.y * loc;`. I tried a few values of loc and it seems to work. I bet it would work for values outside of 0-1.

Answer (score 4):

You have a triangle:

```
  |\             a^2 + b^2 = c^2 = 16^2 = 256
  |  \                     
  |    \  c      a = sqrt(256 - b^2)
a |      \       b = sqrt(256 - a^2)
  |        \
  |__________\
       b
```

You also know (`m` is slope):

```
a/b = m
  a = m*b
```

From your original triangle:

```
      m*b = a = sqrt(256 - b^2)
m^2 * b^2 = 256 - b^2
```

Also, since `m = c`, you can say:

```
      m^2 * b^2 = m^2 - b^2
(m^2 + 1) * b^2 = m^2
```

Therefore:

```
b = m / sqrt(m^2 + 1)
```

I'm lazy so you can find `a` yourself: `a = sqrt(m^2 - b^2)`

Answer (score 3):

Let `s` be the slop.

we have: 1) `s^2 = a^2/b^2 ==> a^2 = s^2 * b^2`

and:     2) `a^2 + b^2 = c^2 = 16*16`

substitute `a^2` in 2) with 1):

```
b = 16/sqrt(s^2+1)
```

and

```
a = sqrt((s^2 * 256)/(s^2 + 1)) = 16*abs(s)/sqrt(s^2+1)
```

In above, I assume you want to get the length of `a` and `b`. In reality, your `s` is a signed value, so `a` could be negative. Therefore, the incremental value of a will really be:

```
a = 16s/sqrt(s^2+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Slope is dy/dx. Or in your terms A/B.

Therefore you can step along the line by adding A to the Y coordinate, and B to the X coordinate. You can Scale A and B to make the steps bigger or smaller.

To Calculate the slope and get A and B.

Take two points on the line (X1,Y1) , (X2,Y2)

```
A= (Y2-Y1)
B= (X2-X1)
```

If you calculate this with the two points you want to iterate between simply divide A and B by the number of steps you want to take

```
STEPS=10
yStep= A/STEPS
xStep= B/STEPS

for (i=0;i<STEPS;i++)
{
    xCur=x1+xStep*i;
    yCur=y1+yStep*i;

}
```

Comment: I think the question is what a and b are, since they're unknown quantities now.

Answer (score 2):

Given the equation for a line as y=slope*x+intercept, you can simply plug in the x-values and read back the y's.

Your problem is computing the step-size along the x-axis (how big a change in x results from a 16-pixel move along the line, which is b in your included plot). Given that you know a^2 + b^2 = 16 (by definition) and slope = a/b, you can compute this:

slope = a/b => a = b * slope [multiply both sides by b]

a^2 + b^2 = 16 => (b * slope)^2 + b^2 = 16 [by substitution from the previous step]

I'll leave it to you to solve for b. After you have b you can compute (x,y) values by:

```
for x = 0; x += b
    y = slope * x + intercept
    echo (x,y)
loop
```